# Sign out by Firebase in Angular4

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I importing `AngularFireAuth`

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

And injecting to my service consructor `public afAuth: AngularFireAuth`, then I create method `logut()`

```
logut(){
      return  this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
      .then(function() {
          console.log("sign out");

  }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("error sign out")
  // An error happened.
 });
}
```

When I invoke my logut method console return me `sign out`, but I don't see any request to server. Where colud be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session is token based. This token is stored in the client (cookie, session storage, local storage). To sign out you would only need to delete the token from the client. Therefore no request is made.

Comment: *firebaser here* This is the correct answer. But we're considering adding a call to the server at some point for extra security, which is why `signOut()` already returns a promise.